# Stop children from scaling by parent scale

Tags: after-effects, after-effects-expressions, after-effects-scripting

So I have a composition with a single image that has this expression attached to its position:

[thisComp.width - 100, thisComp.height - 100]

[image]

All this expression does is makes my image to be located in the right bottom corner. That's it.

But when I try to use this composition in other composition, my children image is scaled together with the parent scale:

[image]

How do I make the image be located in right bottom corner, **but do not scale** with the parent?

Answer (score 0):

try parenting the position values only, not the whole layer.  So pull the pick whip from the child's position values to the parent's position values.